# How can I limit the maximum number of lines in a page?

Tags: setspace

My university's masters thesis template which I have to follow, limits the maximum number lines per page to 25 lines.

I used setspace package which is available in the [revision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/205654/1) of my question but it didn't help me. Also, I used the lines option of the geometry package as proposed in the [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205655/52417) but it does not set the line spacing. Instead it omits the content after the specified line number and consequently, the rest of the page will be remained. Here is the second code I used with geometry option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[top=35mm, outer=35mm, inner=25mm, lines=22]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let us see how to show the edges of the margins (`showframe` option), the numbers of lines (with `lineno` package and `\linenumbers` command) and `\the\textheight`of the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=35mm,tmargin=35mm, bmargin=35mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
THE TEXT HEIGHT: \the\textheight\\

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

There are 47 lines in roughly 646pt with the desired margins. The goal is obtain 22 lines without change the text height. Right?

**Solution 1**. Use the `\setstretch{2.2}` (need the `setspace` package)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=35mm,tmargin=35mm, bmargin=35mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2.2}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
THE TEXT HEIGHT: \the\textheight\\ 

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2**: set `\baselineskip` at 29pt in the body of the document

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=35mm,tmargin=35mm, bmargin=35mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\baselineskip=29pt % not in the preamble

\linenumbers
THE TEXT HEIGHT: \the\textheight\\ %646pt

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

**Solution 3**: fix `\linespread`  to 2.2 in the preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=35mm,tmargin=35mm, bmargin=35mm,showframe]{geometry}
\linespread{2.2}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
THE TEXT HEIGHT: \the\textheight\\ 

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

In solution 1,2 and 3: the ouput is the same:

[image: MWE1]

**Solution 4**. Use the `grid` package with the options `lines` **and** `baseline`. Only useful if you are a fan of the grid format and the package limitations are not a problem in your document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=35mm,tmargin=35mm, bmargin=35mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[baseline=29.35pt,lines=22]{grid}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
THE TEXT HEIGHT: \the\textheight\\ 

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Answer (score 7):

Use `lines`  option in `geometry` package. The following is taken from its documentation on page 16.

[image]

If you don't know how to display the documentation, type `texdoc geometry` on your terminal (Linux) or DOS prompt (MS Windows).

Comment: It doesn't work when I define margins? `\RequirePackage[top=35mm, bottom=25mm, outer=35mm, inner=25mm, lines=22]{geometry}
`

Comment: I am using bidi xelatex package.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - Note that the excerpted examples in this answer specify the options `top` (or `tmargin`) and `lines` but *not* the `bottom` margin as well. (If `top` and `bottom` are both specified, `lines` is calculated directly, and any `lines` option is irrelevant.)

Comment: I tried this. The lines code does not change the vertical space between the lines. Instead it omits the lines after #22 and the remaining space is white. For instance, half of the page will be white!

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: It is better if you add your current code to the bottom of your question so anybody here can use it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @InPSTrickswetrust I edited my question.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent When using @InPSTricksWeTrust's answer, keep the `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\doublespacing` commands in the preamble, and then put the `\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=25mm, outer=35mm, inner=25mm, lines=22]{geometry}` afterward.

Comment: @Trold it still does not fill the page. There should be a way to fill the page automatically.

Comment: @Trold The problem with your advice is that, the space of 22 lines is allocated by tex, when you adjust the line spacing by your advice to for example \linespread{5}, only five lines appear on the page and the remaining space is still empty. I mean, it fills the 22 lines space (half of the page) with only 4 or five lines regarding that spacing code.

Comment: But `\doublespacing` uses `\setstretch`, which cooperates with the `geometry` package alright, rather than  `\linespread`, which doesn't? I know the problem you're describing, but I don't see it when I compile the document PSTRicks, I and CFR have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `setspace` and `geometry` but you must use the spacing command before loading geometry. This still has a rather large margin at the bottom so it is probably best to allow `geometry` to figure the top and bottom margin and just specify a ratio if you do it this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing
\RequirePackage[vmarginratio=1:2, outer=35mm, inner=25mm, lines=22]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: 22 lines]

`stdpage` apparently lets you specify a standard number of lines per page and will space them out. However, unless you want your thesis to look as if typed on a typewriter, this is probably not a good option.