# My font is monospace, will Latex treat it as monospace, or what do I do?

Tags: typewriter

I have a custom monospace font. I want to write the whole document using it. The output from doing Lorem Ipsum shows that my monospaced font is not being rendered as monospaced (i.e. some character widths are squished, probably due to the line-rendering algorithms). What do I need to configure on LaTeX's end to make this work right? I am using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setmainfont{MyFont}
\begin{document}
Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello worldHello world hello world Hello world hello worldHello world hello worldHello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world.
\end{document}
```

I would like to customize how many lines exactly per page, and how many characters per line (since it is monospaced), or at least to set a font size and have the whole document be monospaced at that size.

Comment: TeX engines (including XeLaTeX) don't “squish” character widths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `fullpage` will not give you the possibility to set the number of characters per line nor the number of lines per page. This can be done with `geometry` instead.

However, justification will make characters not align vertically, because it's usually impossible that lines contain the *exact* number of characters (including spaces). If you want vertical alignment, you need `\raggedright` and `\frenchspacing`.

In the example, I set 72 characters (maximum) per line and 48 lines per page.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Mono}

\newlength{\characterwidth}
\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}
\geometry{textwidth=72\characterwidth,lines=48}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{3\characterwidth}}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\kant[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first lines with a frame around the text block to show more clearly where the problem is:

[image]

As you see, the first two lines end at the margin, but the third one is two character short of 72; even with hyphenation on, the next word cannot fit, because the space would count for a character and the hyphen for another.

Comment: How do I change the number of characters that fit on a single line? Changing the font size and then changing the textwidth doesn't always align to the available page space.

Comment: If I do this, monospace is no longer working :/ `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}\geometry{margin=0.7in,textwidth=96\characterwidth,lines=48}`.

Comment: @LancePollard Remove the `12pt` option, if you want 10pt.

Comment: It errors without it, not sure how...

Comment: Your example isn't monospaced either it looks like... https://imgur.com/ugsynvZ Phenomena and paralogisms are not aligned at the `na` and `ms`.

Comment: @LancePollard Oh, sorry! I forgot `\frenchspacing`.

Comment: What is `\frenchspacing`?! So random :) Adding that doesn't work either, it changes it though! The ending letters here are not aligned https://imgur.com/ClWtIlj

Comment: @LancePollard By default, TeX uses increased spaces after punctuation. With `\frenchspacing` it doesn't. I edited the example and changed the pictures. Remember that in your font the interword space should be the same as the character width.

Comment: Ok great! My font is ever-so-slightly off  however, any ideas? https://imgur.com/cSu6hWP It works fine in the browser as monospace with no settings not even pre/code.

Comment: @LancePollard Your font is not really monospaced, my crystal ball tells me.

Comment: Arg okay will have to explore that more then :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, be more specific. At least with respect to spacing, `flushleft` avoids uneven spacing.

```
%!TEX program=xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello worldHello world hello worldHello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world Hello world hello world.
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Wrt lines per page, this may be worth your attention:
[How can I limit the maximum number of lines in a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/how-can-i-limit-the-maximum-number-of-lines-in-a-page)

Comment: flushleft doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's pretty clear what I mean, I want monospace spacing, but it's giving me non-monospace spacing.

Comment: It would be great if you shared a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that