# Set a maximum number of words per page

Tags: text

Sometimes I have to write literature with guidelines for the number of words per page. In these cases, I would like to know how to specify this condition, because although I know the [number of words written](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document), I have not found an answer to this question.

It is true that I have tried some tips from other answers ([Squeezing scientific paper to fit within page limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits) and [How can I limit the maximum number of lines in a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/how-can-i-limit-the-maximum-number-of-lines-in-a-page)), but I end up using `MSWord` and I would like to do it correctly in `Latex`.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please provide a link to these guidelines? This is a common "bad request" for many Journals. What about the font size? How many figures are included? How do I count footnotes? I can have half a page of footnotes and 3 words in the main text and hit the limit.These request were for economy reasons, based on cost per page to print the journals. Ask your editor to specify rather number of pages.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I know it's very ambiguous, but it's the only thing that comes up. They are very basic instructions because they are for the presentation of a university paper, not a publication for a journal.